# Opening And Saving Graphics Files In C++

Tags: c++, file, graphics

I am developing a **paint application** in C++. The problem that I am facing is that I need to add the option to save and open a graphics file but I have no idea about bitmap images. Is there any other way **without creating bitmap images** to open and save the graphics file in C++?I am using `graphics.h` header file.
Its old Turbo-C++ and Windows OS.

Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to add support for reading and writing PNG files - it's a cross-platform library and it's free.

You should probably consider ditching Turbo C++ - it's old, doesn't conform to current C++ standards, and is unsupported. Use something a little more up-to-date, like gcc or Visual Studio (Express).

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) or [OpenImageIO](https://sites.google.com/site/openimageio/home) that do handle multiple bitmap image formats.

Maybe it's not what you're after, as I don't understand what you mean by "without creating bitmap images" ?

Answer (score 0):

`<graphics.h>` is a deprecated header, and has been for fifteen years. You will want to use Direct2D, it is designed for the loading and manipulation of 2D images.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the **CXImage** library. It is portable (tested on windows/linux), open source and handles a lot of file formats. Check out those links:

[CXImage Homepage](http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm)

[CXImage on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), or it's open source alternative [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).